# Facebook graph api me/events returns blank

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

I'm using the Graph API Explorer and have given permissions for `user_posts`, `user_likes` & `user_events`.

`me/posts` and `me/likes` return non-empty data, but `me/events` returns this:

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

I do have ongoing and upcoming events (interested) and they are visible on my Facebook profile.

Any idea what's going wrong? Or is it a Facebook bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/04/facebook-api-platform-product-changes

> Testing of our more robust process starts today and the new process
>   should resume in a few weeks, but apps currently accessing Events and
>   Groups APIs will lose access today.

This may also be interesting for you: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#events-4-4

Comment: but this should still work for the admin/developer of the app - otherwise how would you be able to develop an app to demonstrate to Facebook reviewers the usage and get approval?  its being treated as a bug for the moment https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1697903980256107/

Comment: this was just temporary until they decide what to do with events and groups, the bug got closed with a message already.

Comment: @kassim That's pages though, not the same permission.